# Custom Formatter - Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, textfield

I am trying to set up a custom formatter (named `TextFieldFormatter`) for my text fields, limiting them to 3 characters maximum and only allowing decimal values. `TextFieldFormatter` is a subclass of `NSFormatter` and my textfields are `NSTextFields`. I'm using the method `isPartialStringValid:newEditingString:errorDescription:` to do my formatting.

The problem that I am having right now, is that I do not know how to link `TextFieldFormatter` to the text fields.

So, how can I do this?

Comment: Is this Mac (NSTextField) or iOS (UITextField)? Is TextFieldFormatter a subclass of NSFormatter? Are you using `isPartialStringValid:newEditingString:errorDescription:` or some other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `formatter` property programmatically, or you can create an `NSObject` in IB, set its class to `TextFieldFormatter`, and then tie the `formatter` property to it in IB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it leads me to another problem. Do I ask here, or should I create another question?

Comment: You should open a new question. That way future searchers will be able to find the answer (which is the real goal of SO).